# use two different uitab bar in application

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uiwindow

I want to use two different uitabbar control in the application. first UITABbar control i add in the starting windows. and in this after the navigation i want to show the other tab bar with 5 tabs. can any one suggest how i do this ?
Or we need to add a different window for add this and need to show this windows on the click or other?
Please suggest.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/SpecialViews/SpecialViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH10-SW13) specifically recommend against having multiple tab bars in your application:

> If your application provides different
> perspectives on the same set of data,
> or different subtasks related to the
> overall function of the application,
> you might want to use a tab bar. A tab
> bar appears at the bottom edge of the
> screen.
>
> A tab bar gives users the ability to switch among different modes or
> views in an application, and users
> should be able to access these modes
> from everywhere in the application.
> However, a tab bar should never be
> used as a toolbar, which contains
> buttons that act on elements in the
> current mode (see “Toolbars” for more
> information on toolbars).

If you need to have context-specific actions, use a toolbar instead.